# How to stretch the content of a templated MenuItem using WPF

Tags: wpf, templates, menu, header, menuitem

in my WPF application I have a Menu defined as follows:

```
<Menu
    Grid.Column="1"
    MinWidth="50"
    MinHeight="50"
    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
    Background="Transparent"
    Visibility="{Binding Path=ShowSynergies, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}">
    
    <Menu.ItemsPanel>
        <ItemsPanelTemplate>
            <Grid />
        </ItemsPanelTemplate>
    </Menu.ItemsPanel>
    
    <MenuItem
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        BorderThickness="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentlyAvailableSynergies, Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=VM}}">
        <MenuItem.Header>
            <TextBlock
                Margin="5"
                FontSize="18"
                Text="{Binding Path=ActiveSynergy.Synergy, Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=VM}}"
                TextAlignment="Center" />
        </MenuItem.Header>
        <MenuItem.ToolTip>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ActiveSynergy.Synergy, Source={StaticResource ResourceKey=VM}}" />
        </MenuItem.ToolTip>
        <MenuItem.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ent:VisualSynergy}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=AvailableDiameters}">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding SynergyText}"/>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
    
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type ent:VisualDiameter}">
                <TextBlock
                    VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                    Background="Purple"
                    Text="{Binding Path=VisualValue}">
                    <intr:Interaction.Triggers>
                        <intr:EventTrigger EventName="PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown">
                            <intr:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Path=SelectSynergyCommand}">
                                <intr:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                                    <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource ResourceKey=StdMultiConverter}">
                                        <Binding Path="." />
                                        <Binding Path="." Source="{StaticResource ResourceKey=VM}" />
                                    </MultiBinding>
                                </intr:InvokeCommandAction.CommandParameter>
                            </intr:InvokeCommandAction>
                        </intr:EventTrigger>
                    </intr:Interaction.Triggers>
                </TextBlock>
    
            </DataTemplate>
        </MenuItem.Resources>
    </MenuItem>
</Menu>
```

Everything is working as intended, all data is bound properly and updated when it should be updated.
My larges issue is that the final `TextBlock` (the one related to my `VisualDiameter` type) doe snot stretch to fill the whole `MenuItem` available space (see screenshot). I've tried also to redefine styles, but since I am inside the `MenuItem` resources definitions there is something missing and no stretching happens.

[image: The Issue. The TextBlock have a Purple Background to highlight its horizontal extension.]

Looking ot other questions my issue seems related to the bizzarre definition of `TreeView` and `MenuItem` by Microsoft, but I am not confidend enough to start tinkering with basic templates.

Comment: So you want the leaf nodes to be purple? Or what exactly you want to stretch here?

Comment: The purple is just to show the extension of the TextBlock. I want the Textblock to fill all the space to its right, because I aim to bind a command to the click event of the TextBlock itself, and I want to maximise the "click area".

Answer (score 0):

You should define an `ItemContainerStyle` and bind the `Command` property of the `MenuItem` container rather than trying to stretch the `TextBlock` in the `DataTemplate`:

```
<MenuItem
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
        VerticalContentAlignment="Stretch"
        BorderBrush="Black"
        BorderThickness="1"
        ItemsSource="{Binding Path=CurrentlyAvailableSynergies}">
    <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="MenuItem">
            <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding SelectSynergyCommand}" />
        </Style>
    </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
    <MenuItem.Header>
    ...
```

Comment: I see, but wouldn't this apply to every `MenuItem` of the `Menu`?

Comment: Update: I tried and as I thought this lauched the command every time i hover the mouse on a `MenuItem` (like the All99,5 Ar in the screenshot), but I need to lauch the command when the user clicks on the number in the submenu ( like 1,2 in the screenshot)

Comment: The command is not invoked when hovering. It's only invoked when clicking.

Comment: If you want to invoke it conditionally, you could use a `DataTrigger` or simply do nothing in the `Execute` method for certain objects.